# Split mathematical expression string with Regex in typescript

Tags: regex, typescript, string, split

I have a mathematical expression (formula) in `string` format. What I'm trying to do is to split that string and make an array of all the operators and words collectively an array. I'm doing this by passing `regex` to `split()` function (As I'm new with `regex` I tried to create the `regex` to get my desired result). With this expression I'm getting an array seperated by operators, digits and words. But, somehow I'm getting an extra blank element in the array after each element. Have a look below to get what I'm exactly talking about.

My mathematical expression (formula):

```
1+2-(0.67*2)/2%2=O_AnnualSalary
```

Regex that I'm using to split it into an array:

```
this.createdFormula.split(/([?=+-*/%,()])/)
```

What I'm expecting an array should I get:

```
['1', '+', '2', '-', '(', '0', '.', '6', '7', '*', '2', ')', '/', '2', '%', '2', '=', 'O_AnnualSalary']
```

This what I'm getting:

```
['', '1', '', '+', '', '2', '', '-', '', '(', '', '0', '', '.', '', '6', '', '7', '', '*', '', '2', '', ')', '', '/', '', '2', '', '%', '', '2', '', '=', 'O_AnnualSalary']
```

So far what I've tried this expressions from many posts on SO:

```
this.createdFormula.split(/([?=+-\\*\\/%,()])/)
this.createdFormula.split(/([?=\\\W++-\\*\\/%,()])/)
this.createdFormula.split(/([?=//\s++-\\*\\/%,()])/)
this.createdFormula.split(/([?=+-\\*\\/%,()])(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)/)
this.createdFormula.split(/([?=+-\\*\\/%0-9,()])/)
```

Can anyone help me to fix this expression to get the desired result? If you need any more information please feel free to ask.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Splitting `0.67` into 4 tokens simply makes no sense for your purpose.

Comment: @blhsing you may be correct. But, I'm developing a feature where I can edit each character stored in the string, and to do that I've chosen to use an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have string `match()` available, we can use:

```js
var input = "1+2-(0.67*2)/2%2=O_AnnualSalary,HwTotalDays";
var parts = input.match(/(?:[0-9.,%()=/*+-]|\w+)/g);
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: in case if I have formula `Startdate,EndDate=Holidays,Weekoff,HwTotalDays` then I'm getting `['Startdate', ',', 'EndDate', '=', 'Holidays', ',', 'Weekoff', ',', 'Hw', 'TotalDays']`. Otherwise for formula without words is giving expected output. If you can suggest a change then it would be perfect answer for me, thanks

Comment: Check the updated answer which now supports comma.

Comment: still same. It is considering `HwTotalDays` as two separate words

Comment: You are not running my code.

Comment: yes, I did run your code. Maybe something is wrong with my string which is giving these as two elements in the result.

Comment: I checked my string it is having a space between `Hw` and `TotalDays`  is it possible to neglect any kind of situation? Or else I'll mark it as my accepted answer. thank you so much for your help

Comment: Can you accept removing all spaces from the input before splitting?  If so, then just strip off whitespace and then use my answer.  Otherwise, explain what the logic would be.

Comment: yes, I can do that easily while accepting. marking it as my answer. Many thanks for your help buddy. Cheers!!